# User belongs to group, but can't write to folder that's owned by group

Tags: permissions

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here? I'm in a group that owns the "mediawiki" directory and all of its subdirectories, but I can't write to the folder for some reason. I'm connected to SSH, but I've tried re-authenticating to SSH and even rebooting the server.

```
[02.26.2016/10:50:59] myuser@wikiserver $ ls -la
total 16
drwxrwxr-x  4 www-data www-data 4096 Feb 26 10:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 root     root     4096 Feb 23 17:42 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Feb 23 18:20 html
drwxr-xr-x 15 www-data www-data 4096 Feb 26 10:25 mediawiki

[02.26.2016/10:50:59] myuser@wikiserver $ touch mediawiki/test.txt
touch: cannot touch ‘mediawiki/test.txt’: Permission denied

[02.26.2016/10:53:48] myuser@wikiserver $ groups myuser
myuser : myuser adm cdrom sudo dip www-data plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I just simply want everyone in that group to be able to write to the mediawiki folder and its subdirectories.

Comment: Did you log out of your login session and log back in after the file/dir ownership change or group membership change ? If you have more than one terminal open or you have an X-interface running, it is a good idea to exit from everything and come from a clean slate.

Comment: Yeah I've rebooted, relogged into the user, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group `www-data` does not have write permissions on that folder, only the owner can write to that directory.

Answer (score 3):

Your group needs this permission `drwxr**-**xr-x` set it by running `sudo chmod 775 ./mediawiki`

Comment: Yes, that  would do the trick. But I think you also would have to run `chmod -R 775 ./mediawiki` to change all subfolders and files.

Comment: for existing files and folders - yes ) but question was how to create new ones )

Comment: Thanks. Don't I need to add "g" somewhere with chmod so that this only affects the group and not everyone else?

Comment: the permissions contains 3 types of users owner|group|all, and when you setting the permission you do that by numbers: 7 - owner, 7 - group, 5 - all, in total: 775 ;)

Comment: Check your formatting, and I think you have got the permission wrong: you say they need `drwxr-xr-x`, but they need `drwxrwxr-x`. The `chmod` looks ok though.

Comment: formating is now working somehow, what I ment is **-** symbol of missing permission

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of `$ id`? From your question, it is not clear what your *primary* and *secondary* groups are.

A user can only write to a directory not owned by him, if his primary group and the group of the directory are the same and the directory has at least g+wx permissions. (Standard UNIX permissions, not considering ACLs)

You could solve this by adding an ACL to the directory:

```
$ setfacl -m default:user:www-data:rwx,default:group:www-data:rwx mediawiki
```